# getting certain line using for /f yields last line instead

Tags: batch-file

The following line is 181 lines down in `test5.html`:
             `<input id="id_challenge" type="hidden" name="loginChallenge" size="32" value="censored for privacy" />`
(yes, it does have that many spaces at the beginning).

Using `for /f`, I tried getting that line:
`for /f "skip=180 delims=" %%i in (test5.html) do set "stringRaw=%%i"`
but the result is `</html>`. That's the last line of the file, not the 181st. How do I fix this?

Comment: batch might be interpreting all of the tags as redirection.  I love batch but it sucks to use for parsing advanced text.  Someone will be along shortly to provide a better answer I am sure ;)

Comment: Batch was never designed to parse lines of text, hence the reason it 'sucks' at it. It is possible however, that the issue lies with the type of line endings in your source file. Windows based files use CRLF line endings, if your file uses LF only that could cause the issue. What happens if you change `(test5.html)` to `('type "test5.html"')`?

Comment: Put `if not defined stringRaw` in front of `set "stringRaw=%%i"`, given that the variable is empty before the `for /F` loop begins to iterate (you can achieve that by `set "stringRaw="` in a line above `for /F`)…

Comment: this is what happened:

Comment: my code is: https://prnt.sc/uf787w

Comment: what runs is: https://prnt.sc/uf78ho

Comment: this is in a batch file with echo on so I can see what's going on.

Comment: @ohno, does `test5.html` really have more than 180 lines, or are you viewing that file with some word-wrap feature?

Comment: for your first command: the output, https://prnt.sc/ufnd8n and the code I used: https://prnt.sc/ufneg5

Comment: I'm sure the file has more than 180 lines. I opened it with notepad and Notepad++ and the login challenge was still at the 181st line, even when changing the file type. Is it possible powershell could do something like this?